# Error handling using events, checking if an error happened and react accordingly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, error-handling

I have an object, say `Order` where if an error occurs, it raises the `ErrorOccurred` event. If I'm running some code in say, the codebehind for a .aspx page with an public `Order` registered as `WithEvents` and I want to check to see if an error has occurred before I run more code, how do I do this? I can't simply check `theOrder.ErrorOccurred`. Do I have to create a local boolean flag that switches over in the event handler (`OnErrorOccurred`)? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Example:

```
Public WithEvents theOrder As New Order

Public Sub DoStuff() 
    theOrder.DoSomething()
    If theOrder.ErrorOccurred Then
        do stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a reasonable approach.  If there is lots of logic going on with an Order object that depends on knowing about errors, having a Status field would allow easy communication to any consumer what the status of the order was, rather than everyone having to subscribe to the event and track it themselves.

Alternately you could track it internally in the Order and just throw exceptions when critical methods were accessed if the Order was in an error state.  This has the disadvantage of making you do more error handling, but would have the advantage of making sure that any Order consumer handled them explicitly.

Comment: so it makes sense to create an `Error` boolean property for each class I create?

Comment: Erm... no.  But since your class is specifically raising events related to errors and I'm assuming is also logic-intensive surrounding what errors are going on, then it seems reasonable.  Every class doesn't need this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use structured error handling?

```
Try
   'Code that may raise an error.
Catch
   'Code to handle the error.
Finally
   'Code to do any final clean up.
End Try
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315965

This is what it is intended for.

Problems may arize if someone calls DoSomething but thay are unaware that they need to check theOrder.ErrorOccurred. based on what DoSomething is doing, allowing one to call a method and letting it fail quietly can be a problem.

If do something is doing logging sure, let it fail. If it is finalizing an order process..

Brian

Answer (score 0):

Use the Try Catch Block

```
Try
'try your code here
Catch somevariablenamehere As Exception
'use methods from Exception class to get to know the error better and how to deal with it
Finally
'this is optional, If you want to do something finally, like cleaning up etc. You can do here
End Try
'to end the Try block
```